# "Artifact is not fully assembled" error with maven-invoker-plugin in parallel build

Tags: maven, maven-archetype, maven-invoker-plugin

According to [the docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/install-mojo.html), maven-invoker-plugin is "thread-safe and supports parallel builds."  However, when I build by multi-module project with `-T 1C`, I get an error like the following:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-invoker-plugin:1.10:install (integration-test) on project my-archetype: Failed to install project dependencies: MavenProject: com.tavianator:my-archetype:1.6-SNAPSHOT @ /home/tavianator/code/Project/my-archetype/pom.xml: Failed to install project artifacts: MavenProject: com.tavianator:my-project:1.6-SNAPSHOT @ /home/tavianator/code/Project/my-project/pom.xml: Failed to install artifact: com.tavianator:my-project:jar:1.6-SNAPSHOT: Artifact is not fully assembled: /home/tavianator/code/Project/my-project/target/classes -> [Help 1]

The project layout is like this:

```
Root
|--Project 1
|--Project 2
|--Archetype (depends on Project 1, scope=test)
```

The archetype integration tests use the maven-invoker-plugin to install the relevant dependencies (Root and Project 1) to a local repository, then runs the normal archetype integration tests.  In parallel builds, Archetype and Project 2 run at the same time.  When the maven-invoker-plugin runs, it tries to install Project 2 to the local repo, but Project 2 isn't built yet, hence the error.

But since Project 2 isn't even needed for the tests, I should be able to work around the problem by explicitly installing only the needed dependencies.  I don't see how to get the invoker plugin to do that, but is there another plugin I can use?

I reported the maven-invoker-plugin bug [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MINVOKER-191).  I have an example project that demonstrates the error [here](https://github.com/tavianator/MINVOKER-191).

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Are you trying to do integration tests for archetypes? Can you show the full pom files? Apart from that where have you defined maven-invoker-plugin?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to do an integration tests for an archetype.  But the generated project has a dependency on "Project 1", so I have to install it in a local repo or it won't be found.  I'll try to make a self-contained reproducer and post it.

Comment: Or attach it to the jira you have created...

Comment: @khmarbaise Did both :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well, in addition to other problems with the setup suggested in [Fast Build Configuration](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/fast-use.html) (such as some artifacts being downloaded by the invoked project in every run), and implemented my own solution. Instead of the invoker:install goal, you would use the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.veithen.invoker</groupId>
    <artifactId>resolver-proxy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note that there is no need to explicitly configure `settings.xml` or a dedicated local repository. This is done automatically.

Currently the code in the plugin is experimental. If it turns out to be robust enough, I will submit a patch integrating it into maven-invoker-plugin. More information [here](https://github.com/veithen/resolver-proxy-maven-plugin).

Comment: This will actually install the artifact to my local m2 repository though right?  Definitely not something I want if I didn't explicitly specify `mvn install`

Comment: Note that this is also what `maven-invoker-plugin` does, unless you set `localRepositoryPath`.

Comment: Right, I [do that](https://github.com/tavianator/MINVOKER-191/blob/master/project-3/pom.xml#L31) in the example project.  The other thing is I guess this has to be attached to the module being installed instead of the one that needs it for tests.  It would be nice to avoid installing (even to a separate repo) if I just build project-1.

Comment: I've replaced my answer with a better solution to the problem.